# Javascript role handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, spring-security, client

Hi I use spring security to define some role's on server side and to limit the access on some Restful address. The server side is not a problem. The javascript is a problem. I have some link on the client side that I will disable when the user has not an admin role.

What is the bast way to do this in javascrip/jquery? Is there a script that manage this?

P.S.: I'm a javascript newbie

On server side the roles are managed by spring security to avoid unautorized users to get access on them. What i would know is: is there a script that helps me to manage all link that i whant obfuscate to normal user on client side (centralized) or have I to go manually to every 50 link on my page and add a check on the role?

Comment: This is a massively broad question. How you can best approach security can often depend on what framework you're using (if any) and what your server API looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found how to do. On back-end side I don't have to change anything.
On Front-end side I have to add a taglib on my html page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

After I can securize the block that only the user with this role and up can access:

```
<a href="http://www.everyUserAccess.com/html/">All normal user can access</a>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">
<a href="http://www.onlyAdminAccess.com/html/">Only user with Admin role cann access</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

In this example the first link is accessible for all, and the second only for user with the 'admin' role.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate to prevent the link from even appearing from the server side. Because if you just disable it, any smart user can just view source and get the link and run it. But here is how to disable a link

```
$('.my-link').click(function () {return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning false, you can event.preventDefault()

```
/// Disable all Links with a class
$("a").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

       //// check if admin
          if(  isAdminFunc() ){
               handleThisLinkClickForAdmin();
          }else{
                 //// non admin users can not access links..  
          }
});
```